# Can I download and install gacutil.exe without having to install VS or the SDK?

Tags: .net, download, installation, gac, gacutil

I want an administrator to register some DLLs for me, but he would probably prefer not to install the whole SDK.

Can he just install `gacutil.exe`? If so, where can he get it? Do I just email the `gacutil.exe` file to him, and where does he have to put it on his machine to use it?

Comment: He can't.  You can't redistribute it, forbidden by the license.  Send him a quickie Setup.exe.

Comment: Thanks Hans. After continuing my research, I found that the official best practices way is to have a windows installer do it. So that is what I did, I created a simple setup project and all it does is install the assemblies to the GAC. Is this the correct way to do it? Any other suggestions/tips/gotchas?

Comment: Right, the quickie Setup.exe.  Test it.

Comment: Yes, my next step is to test it on a virtual test box with the same setup as the production machine. If it works I will send it to the admin. Thanks Hans!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Hans' comment on my question, it's against the license. The best thing to do here is to create a quick setup.exe or msi which will install the files into the GAC, which I have done.

Answer (score 27):

I got it working by copying **gacutil.exe**, **gacutil.exe.config** and **gacutlrc.dll**. I understand it's against the licence, but you can't get InstallShield in VisualStudio Express so this was the simplest solution.

Answer (score 23):

Old question, but in a pinch on a machine that doesn't have the SDK installed, as long as PowerShell is available you can do this:

```
#Note that you should be running PowerShell as an Administrator
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")            
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish            
$publish.GacInstall("C:\Path\To\DLL.dll")
```

From https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/16/using-powershell-to-install-a-dll-into-the-gac/

Comment: This worked for me. Sadly, it doesn't print any confirmation. It failed silently at first because my assembly was not strongly named (signed). Also, I used https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430568/A-GAC-Manager-Utility-and-API to verify the installation and get the correct strong name.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have any of those niceties that gacutil has :(

Comment: This works awesome yay!

Answer (score 2):

Also an alternative is to just manually drag and drop the DLL into c:\windows\assembly.

For .net 4, I believe the assembly folder is c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly - though I haven't tested a simple xcopy addition in this manner on .net 4.

Comment: You don't have to register it in the windows registry?

Comment: @crush Windows Registry not required in my testing ("Works on My Machine"™)

Comment: @crush good data point of 1 to add to my data point of 1 - hence the "works on my machine" - probably wouldn't work if I had to try it again now 2 1/2 years later.

Comment: You **can't** drag 'n' drop .NET 4 files into the GAC. _[Tell me more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787607/drag-and-drop-a-dll-to-the-gac-assembly-in-windows-server-2008-net-4-0)_

Comment: @MickyDuncan - Thanks for the link. Looks like .net 4 indeed behaves differently than previous for GAC stuff.