# Drag and drop a DLL to the GAC ("assembly") in windows server 2008 .net 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, gac

I've trying to deploy some code to a client machine, where I don't want to install MS windows SDK tools.  This means  don't have access to "gacutil".  I also have not created an installer for my code.  It seems that these might be the only two options in .net 4.0.

In the past I would simply go to start, run, type "assembly", and drag and drop my dll in.

Is this no longer possible?  When I try to do this I get no error message, but the dll doesn't appear in the "assembly" folder.  When I use gacutil on my dev machine it works properly, but the dll still doesn't appear.

Comment: No, the shell extension that allowed this back in the .NET 2-3.5 days is no longer deployed in .NET 4.  Installing an assembly into the GAC now requires a real installer.  Or just app-local deployment, always better unless you are a large company that needs to distribute security updates.

Comment: What is "app-local deployment"?  The code is a modification for a larger application over which I have limited control.  The application requires the code to be in the GAC.

Comment: http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/right-way-of-installing-assembly-into.html

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In .net 4.0 Microsoft removed the ability to add DLLs to the Assembly simply by dragging and dropping.

Instead you need to use gacutil.exe, or create an installer to do it.  Microsoft actually doesn’t recommend using gacutil, but I went that route anyway.

To use gacutil on a development machine go to:
`Start -> programs -> Microsoft Visual studio 2010 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)`

Then use these commands to uninstall and Reinstall respectively.  Note I did NOT include `.dll` in the uninstall command.
`gacutil /u myDLL

gacutil /i "C:\Program Files\Custom\myDLL.dll"`

To use Gacutil on a non-development machine you will have to copy the executable and config file from your dev machine to the production machine.  It looks like there are a few different versions of Gacutil.  The one that worked for me, I found here:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe`
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe.config`

Copy the files here or to the appropriate .net folder;
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

Then use these commands to uninstall and reinstall respectively
`"C:\Users\BHJeremy\Desktop\Installing to the Gac in .net 4.0\gacutil.exe" /u "myDLL"`

`"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\gacutil.exe" /i "C:\Program Files\Custom\myDLL.dll"`

Comment: Also note that the GAC is split for different CLRs. The .NET 4 location is `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\`.

Comment: Why those jerks! (ostentatiously yet jokingly) Why on earth did they remove that ability? It was a perfectly legitimate way of adding GACs. *sad face*

Comment: Can you edit to include copying gacutlrc.dll also as Roberto suggests below?

Comment: I'm glad they removed the drag and drop ability. It's far easier to use the gacutil. /s

Answer (score 23):

In may case, I nedded to copy the gacutil.exe, gacutil.exe.config AND ALSO the gacutlrc.dll (from the 1033 directory)

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is what did it for me as well. I copied gacutlrc.dll into the same folder as gacutil.exe on the server and it successfully registered the dll this time.

Comment: Where is 1033 directory stored? I can not find it.

Comment: It's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\1033`

Answer (score 5):

The `gacutil` utility is not available on client machines, and the Window SDK license forbids redistributing it to your customers. When your customer can not, will not, (and really should not) download the 300MB Windows SDK as part of your application's install process.

There is an officially supported API you (or your installer) can use to register an assembly in the global assembly cache. Microsoft's Windows Installer technology knows how to call this API for you. You would have to consult your MSI installer utility (e.g. WiX, InnoSetup) for their own syntax of how to indicate you want an assembly to be registered in the Global Assembly Cache.

But MSI, and gacutil, are doing nothing special. They simply call the same API you can call yourself. For documentation on how to register an assembly through code, see:

> ### [KB317540: DOC: Global Assembly Cache (GAC) APIs Are Not Documented in the .NET Framework Software Development Kit (SDK) Documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317540)

```
var IAssemblyCache assemblyCache;
CreateAssemblyCache(ref assemblyCache, 0);


String manifestPath = "D:\Program Files\Contoso\Frobber\Grob.dll";

FUSION_INSTALL_REFERENCE refData;
refData.cbSize = SizeOf(refData); //The size of the structure in bytes
refData.dwFlags = 0; //Reserved, must be zero
refData.guidScheme = FUSION_REFCOUNT_FILEPATH_GUID; //The assembly is referenced by an application that is represented by a file in the file system. The szIdentifier field is the path to this file.
refData.szIdentifier = "D:\Program Files\Contoso\Frobber\SuperGrob.exe"; //A unique string that identifies the application that installed the assembly
refData.szNonCannonicalData = "Super cool grobber 9000"; //A string that is only understood by the entity that adds the reference. The GAC only stores this string

//Add a new assembly to the GAC. 
//The assembly must be persisted in the file system and is copied to the GAC.
assemblyCache.InstallAssembly(
      IASSEMBLYCACHE_INSTALL_FLAG_FORCE_REFRESH, //The files of an existing assembly are overwritten regardless of their version number
      manifestPath, //A string pointing to the dynamic-linked library (DLL) that contains the assembly manifest. Other assembly files must reside in the same directory as the DLL that contains the assembly manifest.
      refData);
```

More documentation before the KB article is deleted:

> The fields of the structure are defined as follows:
>
> - **cbSize** - The size of the structure in bytes.
> - **dwFlags** - Reserved, must be zero.
> - **guidScheme** - The entity that adds the reference.
> - **szIdentifier** - A unique string that identifies the application that installed the assembly.
> - **szNonCannonicalData** - A string that is only understood by the entity that adds the reference. The GAC only stores this string.
>
> Possible values for the guidScheme field can be one of the following:
>
> **`FUSION_REFCOUNT_MSI_GUID`** - The assembly is referenced by an application that has been installed by using **Windows Installer**. The **szIdentifier** field is set to **MSI**, and **szNonCannonicalData** is set to Windows Installer. This scheme must only be used by Windows Installer itself.
>   **`FUSION_REFCOUNT_UNINSTALL_SUBKEY_GUID`** - The assembly is referenced by an application that appears in **Add/Remove Programs**. The **szIdentifier** field is the token that is used to register the application with **Add/Remove programs**.
>   **`FUSION_REFCOUNT_FILEPATH_GUID`** - The assembly is referenced by an application that is represented by a file in the file system. The **szIdentifier** field is the path to this file.
>       FUSION_REFCOUNT_OPAQUE_STRING_GUID - The assembly is referenced by an application that is only represented by an opaque string. The szIdentifier is this opaque string. The GAC does not perform existence checking for opaque references when you remove this.

Answer (score 3):

if you have neccessary `.net` framework installed. Ex ; `.Net 4.0` or `.Net 3.5`, then you can just copy `Gacutil.exe` from any of the machine and to the new machine.

1) Open CMD as adminstrator in new server.
2) Traverse to the folder where you copied the Gacutil.exe. For eg - C:\program files.(in my case).
 
3) Type the below in the cmd prompt and install.

> C:\Program Files\gacutil.exe /I  dllname

Answer (score 2):

Other alternatives to an installer and gacutil are GUI tools like [Gac Manager](http://gacmanager.codeplex.com/) or [GACAdmin](http://www.unifize.nl/gacadmin/). Or if you like PowerShell you could use [PowerShell GAC](http://powershellgac.codeplex.com) from which I am the author.

Comment: Wow. GAC Manager is awesome. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the Fusion API is unmanaged.  The current reference for it is here: [Development Guide > Unmanaged API Reference > Fusion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233169(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, there is a managed method to add an assembly to GAC:
System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish.GacInstall
And, if you need to register any Types:
System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish.RegisterAssembly

The reference for the publish class is here: [.NET Framework Class Library > System.EnterpriseServices Namespaces > System.EnterpriseServices.Internal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, these methods were designed for installing components that are required by a web service application such as ASP.NET or WCF.  As a result they don't register the assemblies with Fusion; thus, they can be uninstalled by other applications, or using gacutil and cause your assembly to stop working.  So, if you use them outside of a web server where an administrator is managing the GAC then be sure to add a reference to your application in SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Fusion\References (for 64-bit OS) or SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\References (for 32-bit OS) so that nobody can remove your support assemblies unless they uninstall your application.

Comment: Why are you down here?

Answer (score -2):

You can also just copy the file to GAC using a command prompt.  I use the following batch script to copy the DLL and restart IIS.

```
copy /b/v/y "PathToAssembly\MyAssembly.dll" "C:\Windows\assembly\" 
iisreset /noforce
pause
```

Saves the need to use or install gacutil

Comment: This is just not correct. There is a folder structure in that folder that you would have to use. And the right folder als depends on the .Net version.

Comment: Just one more concern, does it copy instead of install? I test it but it isn't appeared in GAC but the file is still there.

I don't know why this answer is vote down?