# Autofac cannot resolve Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

Tags: c#, autofac, office-interop, com-interop, word-interop

The application below successfully works on our Dev/QA team machines:

```
using Autofac;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ComObjectIssue
{
    public interface IDateWriter
    {
        void WriteDate();
    }

    public class TodayWriter : IDateWriter
    {
        private readonly Word.Application wordApp;
        public TodayWriter(Word.Application wordApp)
        {
            this.wordApp = wordApp;
        }

        public void WriteDate()
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            var wordApp = new Word.Application();
            builder.RegisterInstance(wordApp).SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
            
            Container = builder.Build(); // throws "System.ArgumentException: The type 'System.__ComObject' is not assignable to service 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application'."

            using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var writer = scope.Resolve<IDateWriter>();
                writer.WriteDate();
            }

            wordApp.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

But does not work for one of our customers — Autofac throws the following exception while creating container:

```
System.ArgumentException: The type 'System.__ComObject' is not assignable to service 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application'.
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.CreateRegistration(Guid id, RegistrationData data, IInstanceActivator activator, IResolvePipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder, Service[] services, IComponentRegistration target)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.CreateRegistration[TLimit,TActivatorData,TSingleRegistrationStyle](IRegistrationBuilder`3 builder)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.RegisterSingleComponent[TLimit,TActivatorData,TSingleRegistrationStyle](IComponentRegistryBuilder cr, IRegistrationBuilder`3 builder)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(IComponentRegistryBuilder componentRegistry, Boolean excludeDefaultModules)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options)
```

Reinstallation `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime` did not help.

---

- Autofac version: 6.2.0.0
- Target: .NET Framework 4.8

Is there idea of what can happen or what should be checked else?

---

### UPDATE

MS Word version: 16.0

Today we were able to fix the issue by running MS Word as Administrator. Unfortunately, such solution **is not applicable**, since the client's security policy does not allow to use Administrator permission.

I cannot reproduce it on my side — it works for me with a non-Administrator account. Looks like some certain permission is required, but **what**?

Comment: Maybe a COM registration issue?

Comment: Agree, looks like COM registration issue. But how it can be checked?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not competent enough on this subject to really help you. This is hust a hunch. I'd say your client Office installation is causing the problem. What version of Office is it? Are there several Office versions installed? Can Office be reinstalled? But take my words with a lot of salt, I may be completely off.

Comment: "Are there several Office versions installed" — No. "Can Office be reinstalled?" — Unfortunately, not.

I've updated the question. Please, check it.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac

Comment: To see what's installed in the GAC for Word: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\gacutil -l | find /i "Microsoft" | find /i "Word"

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572516/can-i-download-and-install-gacutil-exe-without-having-to-install-vs-or-the-sdk

Comment: It might be related to why it works only for Administrator?

Comment: Is this on a server?

Comment: You may consider using NuGet package: `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` or `NPOI` instead of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

Comment: "Is this on a server?" No, it is on the client's laptop.

Comment: The following posts may be helpful: https://timwappat.info/post/2020/01/24/Office-Interop-Access-is-denied-office , https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/387015-office365-excel-not-working-unless-user-has-admin-rights and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon